# Parsing JSON key and value with a JS for loop

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get the keys and values from a **JSON** array, and use them to construct a table. The JSON array has been obtained **correctly** with AJAX.

```
{"CPU":"1.23","NetworkIN":"4.56","NetworkOUT":"0.00","Uptime":"141"}
```

I want to turn the array above, into a table constructed like this.

```
<tbody id="resourceTable">
<tr>
    <td>CPU</td>
    <td>1.23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>NetworkIN</td>
    <td>4.56</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>NetworkOUT</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Uptime</td>
     <td>141</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I've used the following code, which **hasn't** worked.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var resoruce_refresh = setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                url: "http://localhost/json.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    var data_keys = Object.keys(data);
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        var resource_append = "<tr><td>" + data_keys[i] + "</td><td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
                        $("tbody#resource").append(resource_append);
                    }
                },
                error: function(result){
                    console.log("Failed to get JSON.");
                },
            });
        }, 10000);
   });
</script>
```

This script returns nothing, but the web browser reports a successful JSON retrieval. 
I've tried creating the table by doing:

```
document.getElementById("tbody#resourceTable").innerHTML = "<tr><td>............";
document.getElementById("resourceTable").innerHTML = "<tr><td>............";
```

Neither work.

Comment: Two small errors. This `i < data.length;` should be this `i < data_keys.length;` and this `data[i]` should be this `data[data_keys[i]]`

Comment: ...and be aware that you don't have any guarantee that the order will be the same as that which is defined in the object, so your rows may be inconsistently ordered.

Comment: And IMO, it's a good idea to do your `$("tbody#resource")` outside the loop and cache it in a variable rather than doing it over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an array, you have an object, use the `for in` syntax:

```
for(var key in data){
    var resource_append = "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + data[key] + "</td></tr>";
    $("tbody#resourceTable").append(resource_append);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
var rows = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(rows, key) {
    return rows + '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + data[key] + '</td></tr>');
}, '');

$("tbody#resourceTable").append(rows);
```

I am not sure but I think that `Object.keys` are not standard

Comment: Regarding `Object.keys`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: So with `Object.keys` you don't need an additional check (`.hasOwnProperty`) but it is less compatible than `for ... in`